# about Laplace transfrom, how to show:$H(s)=G(s)/s$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

we know:

$h(t)=\int^t_0g(x)dx$

$H(s)$ is Laplace transform of $h(t)$

$G(s)$  is Laplace transform of $g(t)$

How to show that:

$H(s)=G(s)/s$

attempt:

by integration by parts:

$H(s)=\int^{\infty}_0 e^{-st}(\int^t_0g(x)dx) dt$=$-(e^{-st}/s)(\int^t_0g(x)dx) +(1/s)\int^{\infty}_0e^{-st}g(t)dt$

the first term goes to zero. and the second term is the answer?
second part  comes fundamental thm of calculus.
correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly unless $h(0) = 0$.

By fundamental theorem of the calculus, $h'(t) = g(t)$.

Therefore, $H(s) = \frac{G(s) - h(0)}{s}$. In fact,

$$H(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st}h(t) \, \text{d}t = \frac{-1}{s} \int_{0}^{\infty} h(t) \, \text{d}{e^{-st}} = \frac{-1}{s} (h(t)e^{-st}|_{0}^{\infty} - \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st}h'(t) \text{d}t)$$

$$H(s)= \frac{-1}{s}(h(0) - G(s)) = \frac{G(s) - h(0)}{s}$$